# d3.js - translating multiple labels without rotation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm relatively new to d3 and am attempting to augment a radar diagram such that it rotates on click and the next axis points directly upwards.

The example in which I am working from is found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614).

#### Problem

Currently, when the svg is clicked, I rotate the entire svg by a specified angle based on the number of axis there are in the graph. Since I am rotating the entire svg the labels that are appended to each axis will rotate also (as shown in the following image).

[image: d3 rotating multiple labels: current solution]

The text is currently unreadable and I want to achieve a solution which is more similar to the following image:

[image: d3 rotating multiple labels: desired solution]

I would like each label to stay with their respective axis and also stay upright after the svg has been rotated, but I am finding it hard to achieve this.

#### JSFIDDLE

This [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zennou/3w3yjcqq/8/) is the stripped down code of the current implementation (I left out the numerous failed attempts) and the following code, which would be in the 'rotateOnClick' function is the closest I have came to a solution so far (I haven't used the index i variable so far but my intention was to swap the position of labels with each other when clicked).

```
            g.selectAll(".legend")
            .transition()
            .duration(cfg.rotateDuration)
            .attr("transform", function(d, i){
                if (i<total) i++;
                else i = 0;
                return  "rotate("+newAngle*-1+", "+(cfg.w/2)+",0 )"
                })]
            .ease(cfg.easeFunction);
```

I need to manipulate each label individually and stay aligned with its respective axis and also for it to work with a dynamic number of axis.

I greatly appreciate any help and insight.

Comment: You would need to apply a rotation of the same angle, but in the opposite direction to the text elements.

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for the response! In the code above, I rotate all the elements by class ".legend" by the same angle in the opposite direction, although the translation I think is unique to each label?
 I've put the code above in a new fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zennou/3w3yjcqq/10/) to see.
I'm not sure if I should make unique identifiers for each label, such as "legend_1".."legend_n", this may be completely wrong!

Comment: Your approach is correct, the problem is getting the centre for the translation right. I would add `g` elements instead of the current `text` elements and then the `text` underneath that so that the positioning is taken care of by the `g` elements and you can rotate the `text` without having to worry about its relative position.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll attempt this approach later and let you know how it goes!