# d3.js text rotate issue, numbers display reverse

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 text to draw some numbers, and use rotate to change the position, but it seems it changes more than I expect, as in the screenshot, how to let the left side numbers reverse, I think it may like 3D rotate, I don't know how to solve it , or the text I draw is wrong.

```
        g.selectAll('text')
               .data(sumArr)
               .enter()
               .append('text')
                .text(function(d){
                    return d;
                })
                .style('fill', '#aeaeae')
                .attr('x', function(d){
                    console.log(d, x(d))
                    return x(d) + R + 10;
                })
                .attr('y', 12 * SCALE)
                .attr('font-size', 12 * SCALE)
                .attr('transform', function(d,i){
                    return 'rotate(' + (300/30 * i - 125) + ')';
                });
```

[image]

Comment: Similar but a little bit different question as this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082430/d3-js-translating-multiple-labels-without-rotation  maybe you should do special translate for the text

Comment: Check whether the rotation angle is beyond the threshold where you want to rotate the other way (180 degrees?) and if so, rotate by 180 - angle.